# Fail to connect my asp.net mvc with SQl server 2008 R2 , after publishing my web application on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-deployment

I have an asp.net mvc web application, and it used to connect well to the sql server when running it from Visual studio (on debug mode) . but after i have deployed the mvc web application to IIS 7 , i am getting the following error. The problem when the asp.net mvc web application try to connect to the sql server (for example the web application home page will work well , but any page that require access to the DB will raise the following error):-

```
Login failed for user '<ourDomainName>\<ourServerName>$'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user '<ourDomainName>\<ourServerName>$'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Can anyone advice , what is causing this error ? and the error is mentioning that

```
Login failed for user '<ourDomainName>\<ourServerName>$'.
```

it is trying to connect using the server name and not the username , not sure if this should be the case?
baring in mind that on my asp.net mvc web application , i have the "Managed pipeline mode" equal to  "Integrated"

Comment: Has the Identity of the AppPool been setup on SQL Server?

Comment: the identity for the application pool is "applicationpoolidentity" , which is the same as the  system administration. and when i try to create a custom account for the application pool , i got the following error ""The Specific password is invalid" although i typed a complex password something such as "sW@ssw0rd" . can you advice what might be the problem ? –